# Ideal time to say the Daily Nasi

Tags: minhag, chabad, nissan, nasi

It is the custom of some to say the [Daily Nasi](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/495713/jewish/The-Nasi.htm) on the first 13 days of the month of Nissan. Is there any ideal time of day to day this?

Comment: Probably between shacharis and mincha because that's when you bring other korbanos

Comment: @Heshy On shabbat does it come before musaf? Nedavot weren't usually brought on shabbat so I don't know what procedure would be. Tadir kodem?

Comment: @DoubleAA it might be possible to figure it out from the דרש דרש sugya about the 3 goats.